# Is there a Python fuction to separate a line delimited by ',' into different columns?

Tags: csv, python-3.6

I'm extracting data from twitter and putting it into a csv, how do I separate it into different columns (userName, text) instead of having everything in a single row?

This is for Python 3.6.

```
import csv
import tweepy

consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_key = ""
access_secret = ""


auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

search = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="@XXXXX", lang="es").items(5)

tweet = [[item.user.name.encode("utf-8"), item.text.encode("utf-8")]  for item in search]
print(tweet)    

with open('Hashtag_tweets.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as f:

   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerow(["userName", "text"])
   writer.writerows(tweet)
pass
```

I expect the output of

LINE OF EXCEL:

"b'Irene Cuesta',b'RT @deustoEmprende: \xc2\xa1Tenemos nueva cr\xc3\xb3nica! Descubre c\xc3\xb3mo transcurrieron las sesiones sobre #gestiontiempo en #masterdual #emprendimientoen\xe2\x80\xa6'

to be

LINE 1 COLUMN 1:

Irene Cuesta

LINE 1 COLUMN 2:

RT @deustoEmprende: \xc2\xa1Tenemos nueva cr\xc3\xb3nica! Descubre c\xc3\xb3mo transcurrieron las sesiones sobre #gestiontiempo en #masterdual #emprendimientoen\xe2\x80\xa6

Comment: split function is what you are looking for

Comment: Split function is for Strings, in my case is a List that I need to separate.

Comment: Convert the list to string...